# Meaning of ":" and "?"

Tags: function, syntax, return, ternary-operator, autoit

I found semicolons & question marks in a `Return` statement of an AutoIt script:

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Au3Check_Parameters=-d -w 1 -w 2 -w 3 -w 4 -w 5 -w 6

Func A()
  ;do somethingA
EndFunc

Func B($a,$b,$c)
  ;do somethingB
EndFunc

Func C($a,$b,$c,$d)
  ;do somethingC
EndFunc

Func CallFunc( $f, $a = Default, $b = Default, $c = Default, $c = Default )
  Return FuncName($f) = "A" ? $f() : FuncName($f) = "B" ? $f($a,$b,$c) : $f($a,$b,$c,$d)
EndFunc

Example()

Func Example()
  CallFunc( A )
  CallFunc( B, 1, 2, 3 )
  CallFunc( C, 1, 2, 3, 4 )
EndFunc
```

I know `FuncName()` returns the name of a function stored in a variable, but I don't know what question-marks & semicolons mean in this `Return` statement:

```
Return FuncName($f) = "A" ? $f() : FuncName($f) = "B" ? $f($a,$b,$c) : $f($a,$b,$c,$d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know question-marks & semicolons meanings

As per [Documentation - Keywords - Ternary operator](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Ternary.htm):

> Conditionally chooses one of two responses based on the result of an expression.

For example;

```
Return $g_bBlockInput ? $MOE_BLOCKDEFPROC : $MOE_RUNDEFPROC
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
If $g_bBlockInput Then

    Return $MOE_BLOCKDEFPROC

Else

    Return $MOE_RUNDEFPROC

EndIf
```

So

```
Return FuncName($f) = "A" ? $f() : FuncName($f) = "B" ? $f($a,$b,$c) : $f($a,$b,$c,$d)
```

equals:

```
If FuncName($f) = "A" Then

    Return $f()

Else

    If FuncName($f) = "B" Then

        Return $f($a,$b,$c)

    Else

        Return $f($a,$b,$c,$d)

    EndIf

EndIf
```

Whatever that code's purpose seems a case for [`Switch...Case...EndSwitch`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Switch.htm) instead. Popular use of ternary operator includes conditional assignment. Example:

```
Global Const $g_bState = True
Global Const $g_sState = $g_bState ? 'ON' : 'OFF'

ConsoleWrite('$g_bState = ' & $g_sState & @CRLF)
```